# NODE JS MS Sql Dosnt not Connect to msql ip

Tags: sql, node.js, api

Hey i am and i am making an api here is the source code

```
//Initiallising node modules
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express(); 

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

//Setting up server
 var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
 });

//Initiallising connection string
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '*****',
    server: '94.200.123.222,1433',
    database: 'CUBES_HO',


};

//Function to connect to database and execute query
var  executeQuery = function(res, query){             
     sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
         if (err) {   
                     console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                     res.send(err);
                  }
                  else {
                         // create Request object
                         var request = new sql.Request();
                         // query to the database
                         request.query(query, function (err, res) {
                           if (err) {
                                      console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                      res.send(err);
                                      sql.close();
                                     }
                                     else {
                                       res.send(res);
                                            }
                                            sql.close();
                               });
                       }
      });           
}

//GET API
app.get("/api/user", function(req , res){
                var query = "select * from [osama] where bill_hdr_key = '31'";
                executeQuery (res, query);
});
```

and the problem is that when ever i excecute this it gives me error 
Failed to lookup instance on 94.200.123.222,1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 94.200.123.222,1433",
 the server is up and running and can be access through SSMS . Help Me Kindly

Comment: try with `server: 'localhost' ` in `dbconfig`

Comment: It is a remote server

Comment: Do you confirm all details are correct?

Comment: 94.200.123.222,1433 what is that don't you remove 1433 in in connection host

Comment: Yes now i removed and i proceed now i am facing this error when i removed that

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/Hj8Tohp.png

Comment: can you paste your whole app.js code, so I can get proper idea

Comment: would you mind can you provide full connection details so I can execute from my pc and due to that I shall trace everything. later on you will delete details of db

Comment: dipak its a huge db i just dont want people to know it so how else i can give you the pw

Comment: the rest is aserver.js except pw is same its just one file i am just using it to make an end point for sql so that i  can access its data globally

Comment: https://temp.pm/ use this site and send me private mesage and paste link here I shall delete within in a minute

Comment: This is just for to resolve your issue if you feel not comfertable then it is ok

Comment: @user9638167 Please review an answer probably it will resolve your complete issue and let me know if anything unwanted occurs

Comment: @Dipakchavda its not like if i am confortable or not i was about to send you and the internet goes down .

Comment: @user9638167 ok no worry but I have updated an answer to the proposed solution, so hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @user9638167 let me know also if any issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the respect of your code I have tried to resolve your issue with following code, there are few mistakes you did so I have rectified it here.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const sql = require("mssql");
const app = express();
const port = 3131;

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});


//Initiallising connection string
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: "******",
    server: '94.200.123.222',
    database: 'CUBES_HO',
};

function executeQuery(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                sql.close();
            } else {
                // create Request object
                var request = new sql.Request();
                // query to the database and get the records
                request.query(query, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        sql.close();
                    } else {
                        resolve(data);
                        sql.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

//GET API
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var query = "select * from [osama] where bill_hdr_key = '31'";
    executeQuery(query)
        .then((data) => {
            res.status(200).send({ "msg": "Records fetched", "data": data.recordsets });
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ "msg": err.message });
        });
});

//Setting up server
var server = app.listen(port || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
```

Hope, it may help to resolve your bug.

Comment: @user9638167 see now my bad. I forgot to close connection after promise resolve or reject now it is working fine.

Comment: "msg": "recordset is not defined" bro if you need pw let me know

Comment: @user9638167 due to refactoring code, I did 2 typo mistakes my bad. Now it's working code.

Comment: i am getting this problem is it the connection problem? {
    "msg": "recordset is not defined"
}

Comment: no there is earlier variable was recordset and now I used data so it was typo bug.

Comment: @user9638167 nice to see you happy

Comment: sure is there any way to connect with you then I shall give you instruction